# Create Tuple out of Array(Array[String) of Varying Sizes using Scala

Tags: arrays, scala, apache-spark, rdd

I am new to scala and I am trying to make a Tuple pair out an RDD of type Array(Array[String]) that looks like:

```
(122abc,223cde,334vbn,445das),(221bca,321dsa),(231dsa,653asd,698poq,897qwa)
```

I am trying to create Tuple Pairs out of these arrays so that the first element of each array is key and and any other part of the array is a value. For example the output would look like:

```
122abc    223cde
122abc    334vbn
122abc    445das
221bca    321dsa
231dsa    653asd
231dsa    698poq
231dsa    897qwa
```

I can't figure out how to separate the first element from each array and then map it to every other element.

Comment: Why do you have two of `221bca    321dsa`?

Comment: @smac89 that was a typo sorry. Changed now.

Comment: Are you trying to map an `RDD[Array[Array[String]]]` to an `RDD[(String,String)]`?

Comment: @JackLeow yes I am trying to map RDD[Array[Array[String]]] to an RDD[(String,String)]. Sorry if I was not being clear enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm reading it correctly, the core of your question has to do with separating the head (first element) of the inner arrays from the tail (remaining elements), which you can use the `head` and `tail` methods. RDDs behave a lot like Scala lists, so you can do this all with what looks like pure Scala code.

Given the following input RDD:

```
val input: RDD[Array[Array[String]]] = sc.parallelize(
  Seq(
    Array(
      Array("122abc","223cde","334vbn","445das"),
      Array("221bca","321dsa"),
      Array("231dsa","653asd","698poq","897qwa")
    )
  )
)
```

The following should do what you want:

```
val output: RDD[(String,String)] =
  input.flatMap { arrArrStr: Array[Array[String]] =>
    arrArrStr.flatMap { arrStrs: Array[String] =>
      arrStrs.tail.map { value => arrStrs.head -> value }
    }
  }
```

And in fact, because of how the `flatMap`/`map` is composed, you could re-write it as a for-comprehension.:

```
val output: RDD[(String,String)] =
  for {
    arrArrStr: Array[Array[String]] <- input
    arrStr: Array[String] <- arrArrStr
    str: String <- arrStr.tail
  } yield (arrStr.head -> str)
```

Which one you go with is ultimately a matter of personal preference (though in this case, I prefer the latter, as you don't have to indent code as much).

For verification:

```
output.collect().foreach(println)
```

Should print out:

```
(122abc,223cde)
(122abc,334vbn)
(122abc,445das)
(221bca,321dsa)
(231dsa,653asd)
(231dsa,698poq)
(231dsa,897qwa)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a classic fold operation; but folding in Spark is calling `aggregate`:

```
// Start with an empty array
data.aggregate(Array.empty[(String, String)]) { 
  // `arr.drop(1).map(e => (arr.head, e))` will create tuples of 
  // all elements in each row and the first element.
  // Append this to the aggregate array.
  case (acc, arr) => acc ++ arr.drop(1).map(e => (arr.head, e))
}
```

The solution is a non-Spark environment:

```
scala> val data = Array(Array("122abc","223cde","334vbn","445das"),Array("221bca","321dsa"),Array("231dsa","653asd","698poq","897qwa"))
scala> data.foldLeft(Array.empty[(String, String)]) { case (acc, arr) =>
     |     acc ++ arr.drop(1).map(e => (arr.head, e))
     | }
res0: Array[(String, String)] = Array((122abc,223cde), (122abc,334vbn), (122abc,445das), (221bca,321dsa), (231dsa,653asd), (231dsa,698poq), (231dsa,897qwa))
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert your input element to seq and all and then try to write the wrapper which will give you `List(List(item1,item2), List(item1,item2),...)`

Try below code

```
val seqs = Seq("122abc","223cde","334vbn","445das")++
Seq("221bca","321dsa")++
Seq("231dsa","653asd","698poq","897qwa")
```

Write a wrapper to convert seq into a pair of two

```
def toPairs[A](xs: Seq[A]): Seq[(A,A)] = xs.zip(xs.tail)
```

Now send your seq as params and it it will give your pair of two

```
toPairs(seqs).mkString(" ")
```

After making it to string you will get the output like

```
res8: String = (122abc,223cde) (223cde,334vbn) (334vbn,445das) (445das,221bca) (221bca,321dsa) (321dsa,231dsa) (231dsa,653asd) (653asd,698poq) (698poq,897qwa)
```

Now you can convert your string, however, you want.

Comment: I'm not sure, but your output doesn't really look like OP's.

Comment: `toPairs(seqs)`  will give you `List(List(item1,item2),List(item1,item2)...) ` so it is pretty much which are supposed to come and then you can convert into however you want.

Comment: No, that's not what OP wants. OP wants to create a single array of tuples where the tuples came from each subarray's first element combined with the rest of elements of the subarray for each subarray in the original RDD.

Answer (score 1):

Using df and explode.

```
  val df =   Seq(
      Array("122abc","223cde","334vbn","445das"),
      Array("221bca","321dsa"),
      Array("231dsa","653asd","698poq","897qwa")
    ).toDF("arr")
    val df2 = df.withColumn("key", 'arr(0)).withColumn("values",explode('arr)).filter('key =!= 'values).drop('arr).withColumn("tuple",struct('key,'values))
    df2.show(false)
    df2.rdd.map( x => Row( (x(0),x(1)) )).collect.foreach(println)
```

Output:

```
+------+------+---------------+
|key   |values|tuple          |
+------+------+---------------+
|122abc|223cde|[122abc,223cde]|
|122abc|334vbn|[122abc,334vbn]|
|122abc|445das|[122abc,445das]|
|221bca|321dsa|[221bca,321dsa]|
|231dsa|653asd|[231dsa,653asd]|
|231dsa|698poq|[231dsa,698poq]|
|231dsa|897qwa|[231dsa,897qwa]|
+------+------+---------------+


[(122abc,223cde)]
[(122abc,334vbn)]
[(122abc,445das)]
[(221bca,321dsa)]
[(231dsa,653asd)]
[(231dsa,698poq)]
[(231dsa,897qwa)]
```

**Update1:**

Using paired rdd

```
val df =   Seq(
  Array("122abc","223cde","334vbn","445das"),
  Array("221bca","321dsa"),
  Array("231dsa","653asd","698poq","897qwa")
).toDF("arr")
import scala.collection.mutable._
val rdd1 = df.rdd.map( x => { val y = x.getAs[mutable.WrappedArray[String]]("arr")(0); (y,x)} )
val pair = new PairRDDFunctions(rdd1)
pair.flatMapValues( x => x.getAs[mutable.WrappedArray[String]]("arr") )
    .filter( x=> x._1 != x._2)
    .collect.foreach(println)
```

Results:

```
(122abc,223cde)
(122abc,334vbn)
(122abc,445das)
(221bca,321dsa)
(231dsa,653asd)
(231dsa,698poq)
(231dsa,897qwa)
```